# How add elapsed time to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I add to the list every past half hour? that is, if now 20:59 I would like to have a conclusion like

```
['1:00', '1:30','2:00', ... , '20:00', '20:30']
```

how to add figured out every hour, but I can’t understand what to change in my case

```
time_list=['{}:00'.format(x) for x in range(8, datetime.datetime.now().hour + 1)]
```

result

```
['1:00', '2:00', ... , '19:00', '20:00']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
time_list = ['{}:{:02d}'.format(x, y) for x in range(8, datetime.datetime.now().hour + 1) for y in [0, 30]]
```

**Output:**

```
['8:00', '8:30', '9:00', '9:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30']
```